# How resources affected by installed applications in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, ram

Let, There are two friends Mr.X and Mr.Y. Both are using Ubuntu 16.04 on the same configuration machine. Mr.X is having 16 Application installed and Mr.Y installed 396 Application. Both having same digital needs so both of them are using exactly same 16 application.

Mr.Y never starts any other installed application other than these 16 applications. Then one day Mr.Y got worried by a thought that "Unused applications are slowing down his system". so he asked Mr.X about this problem and Mr.X said"Oh buddy! don't worry they are using only Hard disk space and you are not using those "unwanted" applications so they are not going to sit in your RAM-memory because you are using Ubuntu not MS-Window".

Now my question is "Did Mr.X give the right logic ?"

(I'm newborn baby for Linux-family;This is my first interaction with family members;Hello)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether any of the software is automatically started. For example, if you install the MySQL database server package, it will automatically start when the system does and use up processing time and memory.